# JavaScript/jQuery - Array list does not go across whole board

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm working with `A* Pathfinding`. I got it working however it doesn't work all the way. It works all the way until the last `4` columns to the right. Weird.

It works all the way until X is 10 or less. Which is weird because `Y`'s max is `10`. Maybe it's together? I don't know. But my  map is `15 columns` by `10 rows`. Here is an online example: http://mystikrpg.com/html5/

Try clicking on the right side of the map, see how it doesn't work? Now try clicking somewhere so `X`is either 10 or below. It works, as it should.

An interesting error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined`.

The `8` is the `Y` of where you clicked. If you click a the very first gray block on the right-side (since row 0 is walled off). Then that `8` would say `1`.

Here's the part where it lays out the nodes.

```
// Creates a Graph class used in the astar search algorithm.
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

    var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;

            for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
             row = grid[x];
             nodes[x] = new Array(15);
                for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {
                   nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]); 
                }
            }

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

Comment: If it's possible can you put an example in a http://jsfiddle.net, you'll get a lot more responses if you make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please don't delete your post after someone else has taken the time to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `loadmap` function returns an array of 11 elements.

And when `x_block` is 13 for example, `graph.nodes[x_block][y_block]` returns undefined.

Comment: Yes, it's 10 rows down... but I'm lost. What should I do?

Comment: Well, in your Graph function the first `for` loop counts to 10. So `nodes` will be a [10][15] array. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried making it so it does `x` being 15 and `y` being 10.. but I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ` on line 23 .. which is `nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]); `